# How to store result of is into variable in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, variable-assignment

I need to store the result of a select query with IDs into a variable and use it latter.
I have tried with this:

```
DECLARE
     CURSOR commit_ids IS
          SELECT COMMIT_ID  FROM JV_COMMIT WHERE COMMIT_DATE < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5' day);
```

But I got the following error:

```
SQL Error [6550] [65000]: ORA-06550: line 3, column 80:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have various options; here are some of them.

Sample data (based on Scott's `EMP` table):

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM jv_commit;

 COMMIT_ID ENAME      COMMIT_DAT
---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      17.12.1980
      7499 ALLEN      20.02.1981
      7521 WARD       22.02.1981
```

---

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     CURSOR commit_ids IS
  3        SELECT commit_id
  4          FROM jv_commit
  5         WHERE commit_date < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5' DAY);
  6
  7     commit_ids_r  commit_ids%ROWTYPE;
  8     --
  9     t_commit_ids  SYS.odcinumberlist;
 10     --
 11     rc            SYS_REFCURSOR;
 12     l_commit_id   jv_commit.commit_id%TYPE;
 13  BEGIN
 14     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('CURSOR ------');
 15
 16     FOR commit_ids_r IN commit_ids
 17     LOOP
 18        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (commit_ids_r.commit_id);
 19     END LOOP;
 20
 21     --
 22
 23     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('COLLECTION -----');
 24
 25     SELECT commit_id
 26       BULK COLLECT INTO t_commit_ids
 27       FROM jv_commit
 28      WHERE commit_date < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5' DAY);
 29
 30     FOR i IN t_commit_ids.FIRST .. t_commit_ids.LAST
 31     LOOP
 32        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (t_commit_ids (i));
 33     END LOOP;
 34
 35     --
 36
 37     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('REF CURSOR -----');
 38
 39     OPEN rc FOR SELECT commit_id
 40                   FROM jv_commit
 41                  WHERE commit_date < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5' DAY);
 42
 43     LOOP
 44        FETCH rc INTO l_commit_id;
 45
 46        EXIT WHEN rc%NOTFOUND;
 47        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_Line (l_commit_id);
 48     END LOOP;
 49  END;
 50  /
CURSOR ------
7369
7499
7521
COLLECTION -----
7369
7499
7521
REF CURSOR -----
7369
7499
7521

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

If you want to delete rows from another table whose IDs match the ones in collection, just modify code within the loop and ... well, *delete* rows.

Before:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2      FROM jv_commit_property
  3  ORDER BY commit_id;

 COMMIT_ID ENAME      COMMIT_D
---------- ---------- --------
      7369 SMITH      17.12.80
      7499 ALLEN      20.02.81
      7521 WARD       22.02.81
      7566 JONES      02.04.81
      7654 MARTIN     28.09.81
      7698 BLAKE      01.05.81
      7782 CLARK      09.06.81
      7788 SCOTT      09.12.82
      7839 KING       17.11.81
      7844 TURNER     08.09.81
      7876 ADAMS      12.01.83
      7900 JAMES      03.12.81
      7902 FORD       03.12.81
      7934 MILLER     23.01.82

14 rows selected.
```

Code:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     t_commit_ids  SYS.odcinumberlist;
  3  BEGIN
  4     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('COLLECTION -----');
  5
  6     SELECT commit_id
  7       BULK COLLECT INTO t_commit_ids
  8       FROM jv_commit
  9      WHERE commit_date < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5' DAY);
 10
 11     FOR i IN t_commit_ids.FIRST .. t_commit_ids.LAST
 12     LOOP
 13        DELETE FROM jv_commit_property
 14              WHERE commit_id = t_commit_ids (i);
 15
 16        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
 17           'COMMIT_ID = ' || t_commit_ids (i) || ': deleted ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' row(s)');
 18     END LOOP;
 19  END;
 20  /
COLLECTION -----
COMMIT_ID = 7369: deleted 1 row(s)
COMMIT_ID = 7499: deleted 1 row(s)
COMMIT_ID = 7521: deleted 1 row(s)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

After:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2      FROM jv_commit_property
  3  ORDER BY commit_id;

 COMMIT_ID ENAME      COMMIT_D
---------- ---------- --------
      7566 JONES      02.04.81
      7654 MARTIN     28.09.81
      7698 BLAKE      01.05.81
      7782 CLARK      09.06.81
      7788 SCOTT      09.12.82
      7839 KING       17.11.81
      7844 TURNER     08.09.81
      7876 ADAMS      12.01.83
      7900 JAMES      03.12.81
      7902 FORD       03.12.81
      7934 MILLER     23.01.82

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: And how can I also do a deletion based on those IDs
`DELETE FROM JV_COMMIT_PROPERTY WHERE COMMIT_FK IN commit_ids`

Comment: Which option? Cursor, ref cursor or collection?

Comment: With Collection :)